# ngModel kills output with white screen

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I'm new to Angular 2 and trying to follow along with a Pluralsight course that uses it.  It has me doing two way binding via [(ngModel)]="book.title", but when I put in the following in my book-form.component.html:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="book.title">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I only get a white screen when I try to browse to the app.  The variable is declared correctly in the book-form.component.ts file, and I can do this without a problem:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" value="{{book.title}}">
    </div>
  </div>
```

So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the first example of two-way binding that seems to match the video, but am not doing wrong in the second example of one way variable output.

It's not giving me any errors to work with; just displaying a white screen when I try to hit the app in my browser.  'ng serve' output shows everything compiled successfully.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I think input type text always required an value attribute

Comment: I'm not getting an error; not even in the ng serve output.  I'm just getting a white screen when I try to go to the page.

Comment: Oh, just a note to follow-up, I did have an error.  I just had to open my Chrome debugger console to see it.  The page itself was all white, but the Chrome debugger was more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `FormsModule` in your module

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   //...
    FormsModule
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I modified app.module.ts to include that and it works now.  This teacher seems bad about leaving out important stuff.  I was able to figure it out with the Java EE part of this course, but I'm completely new to Angular.